# Taking a snapshot of a thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a program that consists of numerous threads (more than 100 ones). Because of having numerous threads, the required memory of the program is very expensive, so I can't run it on my PC.

I have an idea to run the program. Let the number of threads is 100.

```
1- i=1, flag = false
2- if(flag == true) reconstruct thread[i], thread[i+1], ..., thread[i+9] from snapshots file[i], file[i+1], ..., file[i+9]
3- run thread[i], thread[i+1], ..., thread[i+9] for one second
4- take a snapshots of thread[i], thread[i+1], ..., thread[i+9], and write the snapshots on file[i], file[i+1], ..., file[i+9]
5- kill thread[i], thread[i+1], ..., thread[i+9] 
6- i = i + 10
7- if(i < 100) go to line 3 
   else i = 1, flag = true, go to line 2
```

How can implement this idea with C++ or C#?

Comment: Please tell us what you're really trying to do that makes you think that having 100 threads is the answer. I don't want to know about the threads - just what the problem you're trying to actually solve.

Comment: Also, you can't kill threads safely in .NET without potentially corrupting the run-time. So any solution with the word "kill" or "abort" isn't going to work.

Comment: Threads aren't that expensive (even if they have a 1MB stack then running 100 isn't a problem on modern hardware).
It's what you do on those threads probably. So the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that you are contemplating implementing large parts of an OS without knowing what the OS is doing for you.

Operating systems manage virtual memory, and running threads. If you have a lot of threads, and a lot of data in each thread, then running all of those is going to be a challenge if the total memory usage exceeds RAM. However, the OS will be using a pagefile of some description as part of the virtual memory system in your computer. This results in the virtual memory size being limited by the HDD size, not the installed RAM.

Now, you talk about backing up / restoring threads. Where to? Presumably you mean to disk. However, there is no fundamental difference between your program doing its own backup / restore to disk and the OS doing that for you through the virtual memory system and its pagefile. In both cases you have ended up with data that can't fit in RAM being stored on disk:

- If you just allocate and fill memory inside your threads, the OS will be doing all the work for you in the background through the page file and, most importantly of all, you have not had to write any code to do that.
- However, if you write your program to save / restore data to HDD, you have written a lot of source code and you won't have ended up with anything better than just letting the OS get on with it.

So if both ways end up with a similar result, it wouldn't be surprising if the performance was similar. And so it is; lots of threads thrashing the virtual memory pagefile is s-l-o-o-o-w. The difference is that the OS has been developed over many many years to make it as good as it possibly can be (i.e. coordinating thread scheduling with efficient use of the pagefile), and you most likely will not be successful at beating it.

This is why thread pools are useful. Instead of setting up lots of threads (each one doing a single task), you submit lots of tasks to a thread pool and let the pool manage how best to go about running those tasks. This is particularly powerful if the individual tasks are not dependent on another task doing something (like posting a semaphore, etc).

Used properly, the thread pool will chew through the submitted task list as best it possibly can given the hardware it finds itself running on. This saves you having to write code to understand the machine architecture for yourself (were you to be interested in optimising the number of threads to the number of cores).

It will also likely result in the virtual memory system doing far less paging to the pagefile, meaning that the HDD thrashing will be reduced to the bare minimum. This is because there are far fewer threads (well, tasks) running at any one time, so only those tasks' data will be paged into RAM.

So that's what I'd do. Use a thread pool instead of lots of separate threads, rely on the OS managing all the virtual memory efficiently, and avoid writing a lot of code that replicates operating system functionality.

If that's still not fast enough, then you will either have to get a bigger computer, or start writing your code to run in a distributed manner across a cluster of computers. Things ZeroMQ and OpenMPI are just two different ways of helping achieve this (OpenMPI is the one classically favoured by the super computer guys).